# How to breakup/run a large SQL query?

Tags: c#, sql-server, performance

I have a table with large number of rows(~200 million) and I want to process these values in c#, after reading them from memory. Processing requires grouping entries by column values in a way that can't be done inside the sql server itself. Problem is that reading the whole data at once gives me a OutOfMemory exception, and takes a lot of time to execute even partially.

So I want to break my query into shorter pieces. One method is to obviously do an independent select and then use the where in clause. Another method that I have been suggested is to use sql cursors. I want to chose one of these methods(or another one if possible), especially with regards to the following points:

1. What would be the performance impact of the schemes on the server? Which would perform faster?
2. Can I safely parallelize the sql cursor queries? Would I get a performance benefit if I parallelize the first scheme(one with where in clause)?
3. How many objects can I specify in where in clause? Is it only limited by the size of the query string?

Any other suggestions are also welcome.

Edit1: I have been given different solutions, but I would still like to know the answers to my original questions(out of curiousity).

Comment: Out of curiosity, why can't you `group by` in your query?

Comment: The grouping I am doing has a different output than the normal group by operator for sql. The group by operator in SQL can choose some columns and apply aggregrate operations over the rest of the columns. I am actually clustering values in some columns together based on some criteria.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have to do the grouping logic in code, you can try to write the logic as a Managed Stored Procedure in sql server which can be used in the groping query.

Check out

- [How to: Create and Run a SQL Server
  Stored Procedure by using Common
  Language Run-time Integration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5czye81z.aspx)
- [How to: Create and Run a SQL Server
  User-Defined Function by using Common
  Language Run-time Integration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2kae45k.aspx)

This will allow you to group on the server before returning the dataset to your client.

**[Edit - regarding your comments on using Dictionaries]**

You can check out my project on [Codeplex](http://mmf.codeplex.com/) which has a disk persisting `Dictionary<T,V>`. This would prevent the out of memory exception. Would be interesting to see how it performs for your scenario. (If you are on a 32bit system, read the note on the intro page).

Comment: Seems like a useful techonology... but I am currently using dictionaries to store the output of my logic and I dont know how to transfer dictionaries from SQL server to .NET app.

Comment: Can you use a temp table as your dictionary, and return the data from it instead after the grouping?

Comment: I added a note on my answer about using disk persisting dictionaries.

Comment: Hmmm... I think I can make a temporary table out of dictionary values, and return that out of my sql procedure.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using sql 2005 or higher you should check out sql based paging.

http://blogs.x2line.com/al/archive/2005/11/18/1323.aspx

It should work for what you are trying to do and is a better option than the two you listed.

Comment: Seems like what I need... I will have to read and see how this works. Thanks very much :).

Comment: But ORDER BY is an expensive operation... any idea how much performance this method would yield?

Comment: Here is another link to check out that might have some better information: http://www.eggheadcafe.com/tutorials/aspnet/fe1e8749-26dd-4db7-9c18-b6ea5c39aa73/sql-server-2005-paging-pe.aspx